# Why can't I commit my code to GitHub?

Tags: windows, git, repository, commit

I have a coding project that I would like to maintain at GitHub.

I went to http://github.com and created an account.

I downloaded and installed Git on Windows 7 choosing the option to use it via the command line.

Through some googled tutorials **I created an SSH key**.

I'm following the following instructions:

[image]

But when I get to "git commit..." I get the following error.

[image]

**What's my next step? Who has been down this path and can help me out? Who knows of a git tutorial for windows 7 that will work so I can get going? All I want to do is get my code up, learn how to update it, and keep learning from there.**

Comment: You're not "committing to github" - you're committing to your local repository. Nothing to do with the github setup, ssh key, etc.

Comment: Edward, if that worked, can you select an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's Windows, use double quotes for your description:

```
git commit -m "first commit"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using " instead of '

Answer (score 0):

Try `git commit -m "first commit"` ... note the double quotes